# how do I install latest version of svn

Tags: versions, svn

after running the command

`sudo apt-get install subversion`

and checking the version of svn using command
`svn --version`

the version was 1.9. But the latest version is 1.11.
How should I get the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

Subversion 1.11 is not in [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=subversion) yet.

You can give a look at the available [PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=subversion) but you may have to install 1.11 by hand if you need this version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so since nobody answered and I got it working. It might be helpful to share.

According to the [binary packages page](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#ubuntu), you can get the 1.11.1 version from the [WANdisco PPA](https://www.wandisco.com/resource-library). (It's not very obvious they have the newer version at first glance.) Although they send you the link to the install script by e-mail, you can find it in [here](http://opensource.wandisco.com/1.11/scripts/).

Download the script and make it executable:

```
wget http://opensource.wandisco.com/1.11/scripts/subversion_installer_1.11.sh
chmod +x subversion_installer_1.11.sh
```

I upgraded successfully from the subversion 1.9.7 Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 package to 1.11.1.

One problem I had stumbled upon was a conflict between libapache2-svn and libapache2-mod-svn versions, so the upgrade couldn't continue. In my case, we don't use WebDAV, so I just removed/purged them both and upgraded subversion:

```
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-svn
sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-svn
```

Note that there are only 64-bit binaries:

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.11.1 (r1850623)
   compiled Jun 17 2019, 17:51:58 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try to update the packages using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then Install using these following commands

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-svn
```